# How can I access only data instead of the whole http get response?

Tags: angularjs

```
app.controller('treeController',['$http','$scope','dataService',function($http,$scope,dataService){
var treedata_avm=$http.get('WS/tree').success(function(data){
    }); 
    console.log(treedata_avm);
    $scope.my_data = treedata_avm;
}]);
```

[How do i get only the data instead of other attributes as shown?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA6Gk.png)

Comment: I do not want to use timeout or callback function and I need only json data to be stored in variable treedata_avm so that i can access it anywhere in the controller

Comment: any help would be appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
app.controller('treeController',['$http','$scope','dataService',function($http,$scope,dataService){
     var treedata_avm;
     $http.get('WS/tree').success(function(response){
          treedata_avm = response.data;
          console.log(treedata_avm);
          $scope.my_data = treedata_avm;
     }); 
}]);
```

Comment: but i need to be able to assign the treedata_avm to $scope.my_data outside the get function, not inside it

Comment: @shruthireddy $http is a asynchronous call, if you assign outside the function then the value of treedata_avm can be undefined since data may not be fetched yet. Learn more about promise: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q.

Answer (score 0):

You're not accounting for asynchronous programming in Javascript. There's lots of good resources on Google, but here's how this example should look like:

```
app.controller('treeController', ['$http', '$scope', 'dataService', function($http, $scope, dataService) {
  $http.get('WS/tree').success(function(data) {
    $scope.my_data = data;
  });
}]);
```